# MVC C# Submit hidden form using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

Multiple forms submit with C# MVC.

The company I work for has taken the approach of having multiple forms submits being done using jquery submitting different forms on different button clicks. My concept should be pretty simple. I have a text box sitting in a form that holds the quantity of items to purchase. I have two separate buttons, one for adding to cart and one for adding to wish list.
The jquery submits the form, but the formcollection in the MVC code does not have any form data.

Is My jquery not submitting the form? Or not submitting the hidden fields?

Comment: jquery code `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#imgAddToCart').click(function () {
                $("#QuantityToAdd").val($("#txtQty").val());
                $('#formAddToCart').submit();
            });
            $('#imgAddToWishList').click(function () {
                alert("Here");
                $('#formAddToWishList').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>`

Comment: form 1 in the view: <form id="formAddToWishList" method="post" action="product/add-to-wishlist">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductId" value="@Model.ProductObject.ProductID" />
    <input type="hidden" id="SizeWishList" value="0" />
    </form>`

Comment: form 2 in the view 
<form id="formAddToCart" method="post" action="product/add-to-cart">
 <input type="hidden" id="ProductId" value="@Model.ProductObject.ProductID" />
 <input type="hidden" id="QuantityToAddCart" value="0" />
 <input type="hidden" id="SizeCart" value="0" />
</form>

Comment: I guess my main question lies around the fact, that in MVC can I submit a hidden form on a view to a different controller action on the same controller?

Comment: Controller code:        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToWishList(FormCollection collection)
        {
            int ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(collection["ProductId"].ToString());
     // Form Collection has NO values

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure form is submitted then i suppose there is some problem in the view. all inputs should be submitted for sure, even if they are not visible (e.g. style="display:none;"). i could be more specific if i would see the view.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Action signature in the Controller and be sure that you're using the right parameters' name.

Just for curiosity, why you're not using ajax for this ? (@Html.BeginAjaxForm () )